# How to deal with files outside IntelliJ project with Git?

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I have IntelliJ project inside a folder under Git control. I.e. there are plenty of files outside of project, that can also be pushed and so on.

Is is possible to track them with IntelliJ too, i.e. push, pull etc?

Comment: Change your source folder to include all of the additional files?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can go to Settings | Version Control and specify the root directory, or multiple directories, that will be managed by the IntelliJ VCS integration. You'll see all modified and unversioned files in those directories in the Changes view, and you'll be able to perform all VCS operations with them.